# How do I reset mysql's root password?

Tags: password, mysql, reset

I'm trying to get a fresh install of MySQL, how currently I can not connect. I can't figure out what the problem is, nor how to reset the password. Currently, I keep on getting,

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Here is my version

```
# mysql -v    
Server version: 5.6.27-0ubuntu1 (Ubuntu)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run this command,

```
dpkg -l | grep -i mysql-server
```

This should return something like this.

```
ii  mysql-server          
ii  mysql-server-5.6      
ii  mysql-server-core-5.6
```

You want this one `mysql-server-5.6`.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.6
```

This should ask you for a new password and it'll reinitialize the tables. Now you can connect like this..

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
Enter password:
```

And, that's the most Ubuntu/Debian way I've found to this easily.

Comment: You can skip the first half by just inputting `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-` and then hitting Tab. It should complete for you.

Comment: The dpkg-reconfigure command just returned "This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.13, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade" for me :(

Comment: @Math1000 that's normal and expected. It just means the database was already upgraded. Proceed to the next step.